# TF 2.3 running multiple models in a loop slows down over time

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have 2 networks, lets call them NN1 and NN2 in a piece of code that does the following:

1. NN1 selects or augments in some way shape or form data from some tf.dataset.
2. NN2 labels those samples, and they are stored in a tfrecords file.
3. The weights of NN1 are reset and NN1 is trained on all tfrecords files written thus far.
4. return to step 1.

the code roughly looks as follows:

```
gen = strategy.get_generator(dataset)

for i in range(max_steps):

  #generation part
  with tf.io.TFRecordWriter('shard_{i}.tfrecords'.format(i=i)) as writer:
    for batch in itertools.islice(gen, queries_per_step):
      for img, label in zip(*batch):
        writer.write(serializer.serialize(img, label))

  #training part
  files = ['shard_{i}.tfrecords'.format(i=x) for x in range(i+1)]
  rand.shuffle(files)
  train_data = (tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files, num_parallel_reads=8)
    .map(serializer.deserialize, num_parallel_calls=4)
    .shuffle(800)
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(2))

  reset_function(NN1)
  h = NN1.fit(train_data, epochs=epochs_per_step, verbose=0)

  #do some more stats gathering
```

When I run just the generation part (i.e. steps 1, 2 and 4) or just the training part (i.e. 3 and 4) the time it takes to go through a loop is roughly constant for the generation part or scales linearly with the number of record files for the training part. However, whenever I run the entire process I start losing efficiency over time and the loops starts taking more and more time than they should. I've also tried to run a case in which the generation part solely relies on NN2, but the drop in efficiency still occurs. (It seems like CPU utilization drops over time which in turn causes a drop in GPU utilization). I have absolutely no idea what causes this weird behavior, or where even to start looking for the problem. Any kind of help in solving this problem would be appreciated.

edit: This is not a case of me repeatedly creating new models in the loop without calling `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()`. NN1 and NN2 are only created once. And including a call to clear_session() does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit seems to be the repeated recompiling done within the reset function. As stated above, calls to `clear_session()` did not help alleviate this problem. Instead I've opted to manually reset the optimizer each loop using `optimizer.set_weights(weights)`